# Get row number of a row that meets an x condition in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello Stack Overflow community, I wanted to get the row number of the first element that meets the condition specified in the query. I am making the queries using Postgresql and I send them from Python.
Here is an outline of what I want:

```
+--------+---------------+
|name    |country        |
|--------|---------------|
|Juan    | United States |
|--------|---------------|
|Carlos  | France        |
|--------|---------------|
|Lucy    | UK            |
+--------+---------------+
```

In this case I would like to make a query where I can get the row number of the first person whose country is France (that is, row 2). Thank you. Anything that is not clear you can ask me.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "row number" unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.

Comment: I have read somewhere what you say. But it seems that it can be obtained in the same way. Also, I was thinking of querying sets using ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I rushed a little. Sorry.
I already found the solution. The following query worked for me:

`SELECT num FROM (SELECT Row_Number() OVER () AS num, country FROM people ORDER BY country) AS tabla WHERE country='France'`

Comment: Since you wanted to get the "first person whose country is France", I think you would want to do a min(num).

Comment: The above was an example of what I needed. Maybe your solution works for me. Sorry, I have a hard time explaining myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
with rownum as (
  select *,
        row_number() over() as rnum
  from mytable
)
select min(rnum) as first_instance
from rownum
where country = 'France'
```

You can play around with this code on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/owzEBHgR7STWBkkpXjra1x/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution that you propose is much clearer and I suppose that it is clean than what I found. I tried it on the page you passed me and in Python and it worked!
Even placing ORDER BY in the query.